# Translate character string to values

Tags: mysql, indexing, replace, substring, record

I'm trying to index a list of items from a MySQL query for my search engine.

Let's assume that I have this list of items defined elsewhere:

- variable ID = 81

  - tree  = 1234
  - car   = 4567
  - house = 7890

Now let's assume that I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
   home.id AS id,
   home.title AS title,
   SUBSTRING(all_items.value, 1, 100) items
FROM table home
LEFT JOIN content_values all_items ON 
   all_items.id = home.id AND all_items.varid = 81
WHERE
   home.deleted = 0 AND home.published = 1
```

Resulting in this output:

> ID, pagetitle, items
>
> 01, option1,   1234||4567
>
> 02, option2,   1234||7890

Originally, I was trying to take each item out of that string and adding it as a new column for each value using **SUBSTRING_INDEX()**. Which works, but I need to manually add a new set of columns for each value I want to record in the search indexer.

Is there a way that I could just "translate" the string values in between the "||" delimiters to contain the value names instead? So in the index it just reads `tree||car` instead of `1234||4567` and `tree||house` instead of `1234||7890` for the other record?

Sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  pagetitle varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  UID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  deleted int unsigned NOT NULL,
  published int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,UID)
);

INSERT INTO table (id, pagetitle, UID, deleted, published) VALUES
  (1, 'tree', 1234, 0, 1),
  (2, 'car',  4567, 0, 1),
  (3, 'house',7890, 0, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS content_values (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  varid varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,varid)
);

INSERT INTO content_values (id, name, varid) VALUES
  (11, 'option1', '1234||4567'),
  (12, 'option2', '1234||7890');
```

and [sqlfiddle] (sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8812b/2) of same

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How's this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8812b/2

Comment: I would urge you to amend your schema, in accordance with the rules of normalisation.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: In which case I would suggest you acquaint yourself with any introductory book or tutorial on relational database management systems.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have time for that. I just need to figure out what I can use to replace a substring of characters with the corresponding pagetitles in a larger string so my search engine will index those values. Even if it's a point in the right direction to a specific function.

Everything I've learned about MySQL has been over the last week. Telling someone that they need to review relational database management systems is not helpful at all. In fact, that's opposite of what a forum like this is used for. If I knew all that, I doubt I'd be here asking questions.

Comment: The point is, I don't know what I'm looking for.